# File paths within my Python script fail when launching via double-click (Windows 10)

Tags: python, windows, cmd, cygwin

I have a python script that reads and writes to files that are located relative to it, in directories above and beside it. When I run my script via Cygwin using

```
python script.py
```

The program works perfectly. However, when I run it by navigating through the windows GUI to my file and double clicking, I get a blank cmd prompt and then my program runs fine until I reach the point where I need to access the other files, at which point it fails and gives me this message in the cmd prompt that opens itself:

```
../FFPRM.TXT                                                                                                             
../2025510296/FFPRM_000.TXT                                                                                             
Exception in Tkinter callback                                                                                           
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                        
  File "C:\Users\rbanks\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1549, in __call__          
    return self.func(*args)                                                                                     
  File "C:\Users\rbanks\Desktop\TSAC\EXECUTABLE\T-SAC_GUI.py", line 705, in run_exe                                         
    invalid_entry, output_text = self.apply()                                                                              
  File "C:\Users\rbanks\Desktop\TSAC\EXECUTABLE\T-SAC_GUI.py", line 694, in apply                                           
    p = subprocess.Popen(['cp', output_file_path, output_file_path_id])                                                   
  File "C:\Users\rbanks\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 950, in __init__          
    restore_signals, start_new_session)                                                                                   
  File "C:\Users\rbanks\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1220, in _execute_child          startupinfo)                                                                                                        
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I am deploying this script as well as the directory structure as a zip for users to be able to unzip and use anywhere on their PC, so it is important for me to be able to run it with a simple double click and my relative file paths.

My first thought was the cmd prompt that was opening and executing my script was in a different environment, but when I run:

```
cd
pause
```

in a .cmd script, I get:

```
C:\Users\rbanks\Desktop\TSAC\EXECUTABLE>pause
```

Which is the correct location.

I am not having any luck with Google, I assume because I can't seem to construct a sufficient search query. Could someone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not the current directory. It is correct when double clicking on the icon

The problem is: Cygwin commands are not in the windows path

You are using python, so don't run simple copy commands like this, which make your script non-portable and subject to variations, requiring installation of cygwin, etc...

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['cp', output_file_path, output_file_path_id])
```

can be replaced by

```
import shutil
shutil.copyfile(output_file_path, output_file_path_id)
```

`shutil` module complements `os` module for file manipulation functions that aren't native in the operating system.

now you have a 100% pythonic solution, native, which will throw exceptions if cannot read/write files, so fully integrated in the rest of your program.

Before running an external command from Python make sure that no python way exists. There are so many useful modules out there.

Other examples of how to avoid running basic commands from python (of course if you need to run a C compilation it's different!):

- zipfile package: much better than running `zip.exe`
- gzip package: can open gzipped files natively from python
- `os.listdir()` instead of parsing the output of `cmd /c dir /B`
- `os.remove()` instead of calling `rm` or `del`

etc... python rules!

Comment: I really appreciate it, thank you! That worked perfectly

Answer (score 4):

**[edit]** the other answer is correct(at least i suspect) but i will leave this here in the hopes that it helps the op in the future with path problems ... and doing something like this is just generally good practice

---

use

```
BASEPATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

at the top of your script

the later

```
txt_file = os.path.join(BASEPATH,"my_file.txt")
```

or  even

```
txt_file = os.path.join(BASEPATH,"..","my_file.txt")
```

this gives you the benefit of being able to do things like

```
if not os.path.exists(txt_file):
   print "Cannot find file: %r"%txt_file
```

which will likely give you a better idea about what your problem might actually be (if its simply path related at least)

Comment: The problem is not the current directory. It is correct when double clicking on the icon

Comment: I'm mixed between downvoting (because it does not answer the question) and upvoting because 1) your rep impresses me and vouches for you and 2) the BASEPATH technique is somehow forgotten and people tend to require that their program is run in the current directory, preventing their code to be run from `PATH`. I personally preach for this technique everytime I can (so in the end I upvoted :))

Comment: For the main script it's more universal to use `os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))`. For example, if you freeze the program as an EXE its `__file__` will be `None`. Either way the point bears repeating that a script should not depend on the working directory to find self-relative paths and resources. It will fail if it's run from another working directory, e.g. the working directory will be `%SystemRoot%\System32` when run from the Windows Win+R dialog.