# Python cannot open a text file outside of an IDE (Windows 10)

Tags: python, windows, txt, windows-10-desktop

I am having this problem with any python script that involves opening a text file. I have tried in various IDEs, including VSCode and PyCharm, and all works as intended. But as soon as I run the python script for real it closes (due to an error opening the external file, as discovered by commenting out various sections of code).

Here is a very simple script which runs fine in the IDE but not when actually opening the python file:

main.py:

```
print("This is a demo of the problem.")
file = open("demofile.txt", "r") #this line causes an error outside of IDE
print(file.readlines())
file.close()
```

demofile.txt:

```
this is line 1
this is line 2
this is line 3
```

Both files are stored in the same folder in Desktop, however when I modify the code to this:

```
import os
try:
    file = open("demofile.txt", "r") 
    file.close()
except:
    print(os.path.abspath("demofile.txt"))
    print(os.path.abspath("main.py"))
```

I get an unexpected output of:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\demofile.txt
C:\WINDOWS\system32\main.py
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Addressing the output

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\demofile.txt
C:\WINDOWS\system32\main.py
```

from

```
import os
try:
    file = open("demofile.txt", "r") 
    file.close()
except:
    print(os.path.abspath("demofile.txt"))
    print(os.path.abspath("main.py"))
```

The output does not necessarily mean that the files exist.

Observe:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.abspath("filethatdoesnotexist.txt")
'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\filethatdoesnotexist.txt'
>>>
```

What you want to do is use the `os.path.exists()` method:

```
import os
try:
    file = open("demofile.txt", "r") 
    file.close()
except:
    print(os.path.exists("demofile.txt"))
    print(os.path.exists("main.py"))
```

So basically, when you ran the file, Python is working in a way that the current path is `C:\WINDOWS\system32`, hence if `demofile.txt` is not located there, you get the error.

---

To see the type of error, simply replace the

```
except:
```

with

```
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried running os.path.exists() and it simply returns True. However, this does still not explain why the try block raises and error.

Comment: @YourLocalFriendlyProgrammer Updated to address that.

Comment: The exception I get is "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'demofile.txt'", however this makes no sense as both the files are located in the same folder. Am I forgetting something?

Comment: @YourLocalFriendlyProgrammer Are they located in `C:\WINDOWS\system32`? If not, then the problem is that Python is running the file from that path.

Comment: No, they are both located in C:\Users\my_name\OneDrive\Desktop\demo_folder

Comment: @YourLocalFriendlyProgrammer So the problem is that Python is running the file from that path `C:\WINDOWS\system32`. How did you run the file? From double clicking it?

Comment: Yes from double clicking it. Also from using "cd C:/path/to/desktop/folder" followed by "main.py", which has the same problem (can't open .txt file). However, when I run it in the command line (by typing "python3 main.py") it works as intented.

Comment: @YourLocalFriendlyProgrammer When you run `main.py` without `python3`, cmd will search for files specified in the file in the paths in the environment variables. Try replacing `"demofile.txt"` with `os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), "demofile.txt")`, making sure to import `os` at the top.

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked. However, I am still unsure why my script didn't work. Should it not run python3 automatically? I have done this many times in the past and have had no problems (until today, strange I know). I do not understand why you method was necessary?

Comment: @YourLocalFriendlyProgrammer Perhaps this will help: https://stackoverflow.co/q/38729569/13552470

Comment: Could you check that link again? I think it might be incorrect (page not found).

Comment: @YourLocalFriendlyProgrammer Replace `.co` with `.com`.

Comment: Thanks, but how come the program was not run in the current directory? Is there a setting I changed by accident?

Comment: Quoting this very nice answer from [File paths within my Python script fail when launching via double-click (Windows 10)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38729661/13552470): *"The problem is not the current directory. It is correct when double clicking on the icon. The problem is: Cygwin commands are not in the windows path"*

Comment: Zenn Thanks for your help, I think I now know why it wasn't working: the python file was set to open with python3 (downloaded from the Microsoft Store for use in cmd) instead of the default py.exe python launcher.